# QML Window FramelessWindowHint on Linux still resizable

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have the below example:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 500
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint

    TextEdit {
        id: name
        text: qsTr("text")
        readOnly: false
        width: 100
        height: 100
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is a frameless window that cannot be resized as the documentation suggests, but in Linux the x11 manager takes over. One way to solve the resizing issue is to specify `X11BypassWindowManagerHint` as a second flag. The issue is when using the latter, one cannot type in the `TextField` anymore. How can I solve that on Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `Window` method [requestActivate](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#requestActivate-method) to receive keyboard focus.

```
Window {
    ...
    Component.onCompleted: requestActivate()
}
```